# items array is not being recognized by php function in STRIPE checkout

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe quick start code found here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart
I have narrowed down the problem to the "items" array in the checkout.js not being recognized or not properly constructed or whatever in the create.php file.
My customers will only be purchasing one type of item at different dollar amounts so this function

```
function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
    // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
    // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
    // people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
    return 1400;
}
```

is useless to me and the amount can just go into this

$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
'amount' => *`calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items)`,*
'currency' => 'eur',
'automatic_payment_methods' => [
'enabled' => true,
],
]);

as the total.
I have tried replacing `calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items)` with array_values($$items)[0]  as well as everything else I can think of. Stripe support has been of no help.
Thank you in advance

The HTML: The price is in cents from the "value"

```
    <select id="item-options"">
    <option value="">---- SELECT----</option>
    <option value="9000">300 ITEMS - &dollar;90.00 USD</option>
    <option value="8000">200 ITEMS - &dollar;80.00 USD</option>
    <option value="5000">100 ITEMS - &dollar;50.00 USD</option>
    <option value="3000">50 ITEMS - &dollar;30.00 USD</option>
    <option value="1750">25 ITEMS - &dollar;17.50 USD</option>
    <option value="800">10 ITEMS - &dollar;8.00 USD</option>
    <option value="450">5 ITEMS - &dollar;4.50 USD</option>
    <option value="100">1 ITEMS - &dollar;1.00 USD</option>
    </select>
```

The full javascript:

```
 var price = $('#item-options option:selected').val();

      // This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxx....");
```

// The items the customer wants to buy  *I have change this to (amount: price)*
const items = [{ id: *"xl-tshirt*" }];

```
let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("/create.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "http://localhost:4242/public/checkout.html",
      receipt_email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    },
  });

  // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
  // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
  // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
  // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
  // redirected to the `return_url`.
  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageText.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

The php :

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// This is your test secret API key.
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_XXXXXX.........');

function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
    // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
    // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
    // people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
    return 1400;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
    // retrieve JSON from POST body
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

    // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
    $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items),
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
    ]);

    $output = [
        'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    ];

    echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: Just noticed 2 $$ it is 1 in the code I tried

Comment: I should also mention that I changed their items array from id: "xl-tshirt" to amount: price. Price being the variable of the dollar amount. I know these values are in the array and are correct by alerting the items array on submit.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what the problem is ??

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details?  Specifically filling in the following info would help a ton: 1) explain where the amount is being determined (server-side or client-side) 2) include any error messages you've encountered 3) provide more of your server-side code as well as the relevant client-side code.

Comment: Thank you Justin. The javascript is a bit messed up in the edit above and I can't seem to fix it but this line // The items the customer wants to buy ***I have change this to (amount: price)****  const items = [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }];  is part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent price manipulation on the client side you should pass to your PHP script ids of products, not the prices directly. By knowing the product ids,  you can [search for prices](https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-prices) on the server side. That's what the `calculateOrderAmount` function is for in your example code.

Since you intended to sell only one type of product, the price of which will depend on the volume, you may want to send a number of items from the client. Then take a look at [tiered pricing](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#tiered-pricing) and make the code match your pricing model.

Comment: Thank you Seeker. The price is dynamically entered into a disabled hidden input field by with onClick event when user selects from the dropdown box. Then it is grabbed and entered into the ITEMS array as "amount: price". I don't believe there is anyway the user can manipulate the price. If I am wrong, please tell me so I can prevent it. Thank you for your input.

Comment: To avoid price manipulation for sure, you should get the prices from the Stripe database. All your Javascript code resides inside the customer's browser. Anyone can open the developer console and get full access to your logic and data before it is sent to the server. However, if you're selling material goods and manually checking orders, you definitely don't need the hidden input field or the `calculateOrderAmount` function. Just pass the price from the `select` input.

Comment: You have me convinced that this would be a better method. However, I am not sure how to implement it. So, what you are saying is if I left the "items array" with the API ID as "id: price_1KteWblahblahblah " the calculateOrderAmount function would automatically look up the and return the corresponding price ?  I don't see how, since the function doesn't reference any database or file?

Comment: The basic part to solve your problem is described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72069175/14648074). However, if you're only having problems querying the database, it can be solved something like this: `$priceSearchResult = \Stripe\Price::search(["query"  => "product:'" . $productId . "'"]);`. The price object will be the first element of `data` array in the result, i.e. `$priceSearchResult->data[0]` and amount: `$priceSearchResult->data[0]->unit_amount`. Stripe has the great docs about their API. Don't hesitate to [dive into](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/search?lang=php).

Comment: Thank you VERY much for that answer, Seeker. This was very helpful as I am not a coder but I do have some knowledge of coding. I am also not a hacker and was completely unaware that the price could be manipulated in the dev tools. I tried it and seen it for myself. I am making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing a var_dump($items) in the php file and the console.log showed it as a stdClass Object. Using  "$amount = $items[0]->amount;" in the "function calculateOrderAmount(array $items)" now gives me the correct price for the "$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items),"

Thank you Justin for responding to my question.